# Test lengthy form without re-writing all the fill_ins everytime

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I have a long form, and for 3 of the fields, I need to test whether those were filled out right or wrong individually, because errors lead to very different actions. But it's very tedious and not DRY to write integration tests like this:

```
# Test 1

describe "test where field3 fails" do

  before do
    fill_in "field1", with: "passing info"
    fill_in "field2", with: "passing info"
    fill_in "field3", with: "not passing info"
    ...
  end

  it "should lead to an error specific to field3" do
    ...
  end

end

# Test 2

describe "test where field2 fails" do

  before do
    fill_in "field1", with: "passing info"
    fill_in "field2", with: "not passing info"
    fill_in "field3", with: "passing info"
    ...
  end

  it "should lead to an error specific to field2" do
    ...
  end

end

# Test 3

describe "test where field1 fails" do

  before do
    fill_in "field1", with: "not passing info"
    fill_in "field2", with: "passing info"
    fill_in "field3", with: "passing info"
    ...
  end

  it "should lead to an error specific to field1" do
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case ,I would suggest to write data driven tests like below

```
     describe "test all form fields" do |data|

  before do
    fill_in "field1", with: data[0]
    fill_in "field2", with: data[1]
    fill_in "field3", with: data[2]
    ...
  end   

  it "should lead to an error message" do |CorrespondingErrorMsg|
    ...
  end
```

This way all the combinations will be defined inside test data ,not in the code so in future if no. of validations even increase or decrease you don't have to touch the code.Only the data.
I hope it makes sense to make the solution dry.

Comment: I like the idea of using a hash! The challenge though is not every field is a `fill_in`, some are `check`, some are even `page.execute_script`. But you're making me wonder if I could the entire line of code in the hash: such that the hash looks like `{code: "fill_in 'field1', with: 'passing data'", outcome: "error message" }`. If I did this, is there a way to get the code to evaluate as a line of code and not a string?

Comment: The whole idea is keep the code simple and separate from the test data combinations.You can have any type of field but the action would be taken based on supplied data.Ex:checkbox to be selected can be supplied as Y/N from testdata which can be kept in external csv/xml/text file.

Comment: My idea was simply to use data driven tests using arrays and running multiple iterations.

Comment: I'm going to use an eval I think, will follow up to ensure it works. Yes I'm following your idea